# Convert Java object to BigQuery TableRow

Tags: dataflow

I am exploring Google Cloud Dataflow.

I was wondering if automatic conversion between java object or JSON  to TableRow can be done.

Just like we can automatically parse JSON to POJO class.

I could not find relevant information.
Hope not to duplicate question.

Will be grateful for any info!

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looking for examples for the same with no luck. I created a POJO class that almost match the schema of the bigquery table and matches the structure of the JSON objects that are the input for the pipeline. Finally, when I have to convert those objects to TableRow, for the nested and repeated values I made something like below, and the conversion was made by the API

```
    TableRow row = new TableRow()
            .set("items", c.element().getItems())
            .set("orderDate", c.element().getOrderDate())
            .set("orderNumber", c.element().getOrderNumber());
```

Where Item class is part of the Order object :

```
@JsonProperty("items")
private List<Item> items = null;
```

This is the code for Item class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "id",
    "code",
    "detail",
    "name",
    "shortName",
    "description",
    "sku",
    "quantity",
    "category",
    "products"
})
public class Item implements Serializable
{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty("detail")
    private String detail;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("shortName")
    private String shortName;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty("sku")
    private String sku;
    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    private Integer quantity;
    @JsonProperty("category")
    private Category category;
    @JsonProperty("products")
    private List<Product> products = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -5644586446669059821L;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @JsonProperty("detail")
    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    @JsonProperty("detail")
    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("shortName")
    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("shortName")
    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @JsonProperty("description")
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonProperty("sku")
    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    @JsonProperty("sku")
    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @JsonProperty("category")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    @JsonProperty("category")
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @JsonProperty("products")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

@JsonProperty("products")
public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
}
```

And this is the schema of the BigQuery table in regards Items, where Item is a RECORD and REPEATED field and also contain a nested RECORD and REPEATED field: products. See the screenshot of the schema

[Item schema fields in BQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIfPo.png)